# how to open a site without closing an app

Tags: uiwebview

I have been opening websites in my app in the following:

```
NSURL * url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

But this terminates the app before opening the site. How can I keep the app running in the background/paused while I open the site?

Comment: add a UIWebView to load & display the website

Answer (score 0):

try this, its work properly

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
                      [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```